# Trailing zero for string values in Database in Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a program which reads data from excel file and then loads them into database. database version Oracle 11.2g.

[image: Sample Excel Data]

if I am using below code to parse the values from excel -

```
sku = int(worksheet.cell(r, 0).value)
color = int(worksheet.cell(r, 1).value)
```

I am getting exception

```
File "uda_upload_automator.py", line 125, in perform_database_operations
    cursor.executemany(statement, row)
TypeError: expecting string or bytes object
```

when i am changing it to

```
sku = str(worksheet.cell(r, 0).value).strip()
val = str(worksheet.cell(r, 1).value).strip()
```

it's loaded into database but Style number and color code are coming as

```
210374245.0 3985.0
210377506.0 3985.0
```

But I dont need trailing zero. 
Code I am using to insert into database.

```
    cursor.setinputsizes(25, 3, 5, 3, 2)
    statement = """INSERT INTO {0}.uda_upload_stage VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)""".format(usr)
    cursor.executemany(statement, row)
```

Comment: What type is this column?

Comment: @Mureinik  In database item column is VARCHAR2(25) and color is VARCHAR2(10)

Comment: Why you store int as varchar?

Comment: Because this is the way it is now. I cant change DB column details so I will have to think something else in my code.